# SQL Server Pivot table for survey responses

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, unpivot

I have a sql server table called surveys with the following data

```
+------------+--------------+----+----+----+----+
| ModuleCode | SurveyNumber | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 | Q4 |
+------------+--------------+----+----+----+----+
| NME3519    |            1 |  5 |  4 |  5 |  3 |
| NME3519    |            2 |  3 |  3 |  2 |  1 |
| NME3519    |            3 |  4 |  3 |  2 |  1 |
| NME3520    |            1 |  4 |  3 |  2 |  1 |
| NME3519    |            4 |  4 |  2 |  2 |  1 |
+------------+--------------+----+----+----+----+
```

I'd like to be able to report on one module at a time and for the result to be something like this:

```
            Count of scores
+----------+---+---+---+---+---+
| Question | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
+----------+---+---+---+---+---+
| Q1       | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| Q2       | 0 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| Q3       | 0 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| Q4       | 3 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
+----------+---+---+---+---+---+
```

I'm pretty sure from other examples I need to unpivot and then pivot but I can't get anywhere with my own data.

Many thanks

Richard

Comment: UNION ALL, GROUP BY, case expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unpivot and aggregate:

```
select v.question,
       sum(case when v.score = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as score_1,
       sum(case when v.score = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as score_2,
       sum(case when v.score = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as score_3,
       sum(case when v.score = 4 then 1 else 0 end) as score_4,
       sum(case when v.score = 5 then 1 else 0 end) as score_5
from responses r cross apply
     ( values ('Q1', r.q1), ('Q2', r.q2), ('Q3', r.q3), ('Q4', r.q4), ('Q5', r.q5)
     ) v(question, score)
group by v.question;
```

This version uses a lateral join for unpivoting.  I find the syntax simpler and lateral joins more powerful.  Why bother learning `unpivot` when something else does the same thing more concisely, more powerfully, and has the same performance?

As for the pivoting, it uses conditional aggregation.  In my experience with SQL Server, this has pretty much the same performance as `pivot`.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, it works great for reporting on all ModuleCode, struggling to work out how to specify a specific ModuleCode, do I need a where clause?

Comment: Got it, just needed r.Module = 'NME3520' before the group by, thanks again